# Mule JSON validation Schema component avoid error logs

Tags: json, mule

I'm using JSON Validation Schema component and I have notice, that it logs all the errors to the console.

I would like to avoid this error message being displayed in the console.

Even though I have chosen a special exception strategy which has catch exception strategy with JSONValidation Exception and has custom logic implemented and no loggers at all in it, I still see the following error message:

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Json content is not compliant with schema
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ListProcessingReport: failure
--- BEGIN MESSAGES ---
error: string "blah" is too long (length: 4, maximum allowed: 3)
    level: "error"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/...}
    instance: {"pointer":"/blah_blah_code"}
    domain: "validation"
    keyword: "maxLength"
    value: "blah"
    found: 4
    maxLength: 3
---  END MESSAGES  ---
```

How could I make mule omit this error message? I don't want these errors to be logged to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the logException attribute of the [catch-exception-strategy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/catch-exception-strategy) element to false, forcing mule not to log errors to the console:

```
<catch-exception-strategy logException="false">
```

Comment: This is not logging the exceptions... But whenever there is an validation exception is thrown, people are getting notifications(Anypoint Alert Notifications) that this application has failed during so and so time. Is there a way to avoid mule to throw an exception for JSON Validation component?

Comment: You can't avoid exceptions if the validation is actually failing, but just like you can hide the logs you can avoid notifications from the error by setting `enableNotifications=false` in the exception strategy. I'd suggest using a choice exception strategy so as to only apply those rules to the validator exception. HTH

Answer (score 0):

set below logger to false in log4j2.xml

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.apikit.validation.RestJsonSchemaValidator" level="OFF"/>
```